# Attempting to prevent submitting empty form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form in my HTML document, and it only has a "text" input, and a submit button.
I also have JavaScript that checks if the field is empty and returns true or false.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HBZ7t/

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="checkNull();" method="post">
<input type="text" id="field">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function checkNull() {
var field = document.getElementById("field");
    if(field.value !== "") {
    return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

However, the form can be submitted even if the text field is empty... Any suggestions?

Comment: simple example from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validation and its working in safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nearly everything right, you just need to return the value from the function to the handler:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkNull();" method="post">
// -------------^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can use double exclamation points to check for lots of non-valid settings:

```
function checkNull() {
  var field = document.getElementById("field");
  if(!!field.value) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/65G7E/3/)**

JS

```
var form=document.getElementById("form");
form.onsubmit=function(){
 var field = document.getElementById("field");
    if (field.value !== "") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="field">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use event.preventDefault() to cancel a event, see [mozila doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Also, check [the very nice jQuery submit function and samples here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Check this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HBZ7t/5/

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

  if($('#field').val()=='')
  {
    alert('cancel event');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```